# How does cognito user operate specific folder on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have a cognito user pool, and in the pool I have several users.
The problem is, how can I use policy to grant permission for cognito user to access specific folder in S3 bucket?

Here is my IAM policy,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt15057XXXXXXX",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:getObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::exampleBucket/folder1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I attach this policy to a role which type is Web Identity, Amazon cognito. Then I connect this role to the cognito user group. When any user register the account, I will put the user into the user group. The user should restrict to the role and only can get objects in the specific folder.

But I don't know why it doesn't work.

I want to know if there's any problem in my policy or there is some other problems that I didn't notice ? Thanks!

Update, to Rachit Dhall,
I am confused about "authenticate provider"

Do you mean cognito->manager federated Identities-> edit identity pool -> authentication provider ?

If so, I already set authentication with cognito. But still doesn't work.
The error message is still Access Denied.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the Cognito User Pool as an authentication provider in the Cognito Identity Pool. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I already update my question. Please take a look at it. thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please PM me your identity pool id, would be happy to help on this.

Comment: sorry but i don't have the right to provide identity pool id :(